# using socat or stream to read from serial?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, serial-port, serial-console

I am trying to send a binary file from Raspbian to an ESP32 device on a RPI USB port, and read response data.
I can `cat file > /dev/ttyS0`, but obviously ">" discards output from the device/input to the session, so my device gets the data I'm sending it but I have no way to read the response. It's 6KB of binary data so cut-n-paste into a serial monitor won't work.
I am trying to determine if there's a serial console program like minicom or screen that can establish a bidirectional connection to the serial device, then open a file and send the contents, or if there's some combination of screen/socat or something else that can redirect its output to the serial device and repeat/display what comes back.

Comment: most commonly, you'd expect some kind of protocol, where one side says how many bytes (typically, not many kilobytes) they're going to send, which the other side acknowledges, which the first side takes as reason to start sending, often/typically attaching a checksum, and then after the specified bytes have been received (and checked, if with checksum), the second side confirms reception, which allows the first side to send the next packet. Is this the case here, too?

Comment: No, the communication is primarily one-way. I'm (normally) reading serial data from a device (a boat's wind instrument) and my ESP32 is interpreting the protocol. But for debugging, I dumped the raw data into a binary file and am sending the file to the ESP32. However, I need a way to read the ESP32's responses on the serial port.

Comment: Socat can do bidirectional communications. Try something like this, where output stays connected to stdout (terminal):
cat /path/to/file | socat - FILE:/dev/ttyS0,cfmakeraw